# Installation of Matplotlib2Tikz

Tags: software-installation

I have read the "Readme" but I am totally stupid. So could anyone please tell me how I install it on Linux?

https://github.com/nschloe/matplotlib2tikz

I know how to download the Zip. And well, that is it then. Hopefully someone can help :-)

I don't know where the $PYTHONPATH is. But well, when I know where to place it (and how), I have to use this peace of code, right?

```
 sudo python setup.py install
```

And then everything should be done? And I can use it with placing the "from ..." and the "tikz-..."?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: And you are running Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes :-) ...  I don't know where to place the unzipped file.

Answer (score 1):

[Since matplotlib2tikz is on PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/matplotlib2tikz), you can install it by

```
sudo -H pip install matplotlib2tikz
```